# How to represent bipolar survey question in ggplot2 with multiple axes labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data from a survey from a question of the format

```
| Statement A | Agree strongly w/ A| ... | Agree strongly w/ B | Statement B |
| A1          |         o          | ... |          o          | B1          |
```

I would like to display the means of each statement with a bar chart that has labels on either side of the bar - one on the left for statement A and one on the right for statement B, like so:

[image: graph sketch]
<sub>(source: [tomvladeck.com](http://tomvladeck.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Screenshot-2017-02-08-12.28.43.png))</sub>

I'd like to have y axis lines where you see the line under the labels "Statement A" and "Statement B", and y axis labels where you see the boxed "A1", "A2", and "B1", "B2". With `ggplot` when using `scale_y_discrete` you can only have one line (as far as I know) and can move it to the right side with `position = "right"`, but afaik, you can't have two axis lines (even if they are the same scale).

This isn't having multiple `y` scales, which I know isn't natively supported by `ggplot2`. Technically it's having one discrete y scale, but with two sets of labels, but I don't know how to implement this in `ggplot2` other than using lots of `annotates`. Any help here? Is this possible to do in natural ggplot?

Here is a minimal reprex:

```
example_df <- 
  data.frame(
    statement_a = c("I like to take risks", 
                    "I work to provide for my family"),
    statement_b = c("I am more risk averse",
                    "I work to provide for myself"),
    value = c(-1.5, .5)
  )

plot_1 <- 
  ggplot(example_df, 
         aes(x = statement_a, y = value)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "")

plot_2 <- 
    ggplot(example_df, 
         aes(x = statement_b, y = value)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "", position = "top")
```

Plot A looks like this:
[image: Plot A]
<sub>(source: [tomvladeck.com](http://tomvladeck.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/plot_a.jpeg))</sub>

Plot B looks like this:
[image: Plot B]
<sub>(source: [tomvladeck.com](http://tomvladeck.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/plot_b.jpeg))</sub>

And the idea is to show *both* of the axis lines (the one on the left in A, and the one on the right in B)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @MichaelChernick edited to make more clear, but the question is how to add multiple axis lines and labels for the same discrete scale in ggplot2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: @gung i'll add a reprex, but having a reprex and being on or off topic are orthogonal issues.

Comment: You're right that this would be off topic even w/ a reproducible example, but it would be on topic on [SO] then, & so we could migrate it for you. That's my point, ultimately.

Comment: @gung I *obviously* was not saying that this would be off topic w/out a reprex, so I don't appreciate you attributing those words to me. This is about how to use ggplot to represent a very common survey question - both ggplot (and data visualization in general) and surveys are incredibly relevant topics to statistics, so what, exactly, is off topic here?

Comment: Questions about how to use software (eg, how to make a given plot in ggplot) are generally off topic here. Your question, as posted, was off topic here & on SO; if you add a reproducible example, it will still be off topic here, but would be migrateable to SO where you could get the help you want. I'm trying to help you get the assistance you are after.

Comment: @gung - I added a reprex, let's migrate this to SO then. How do I do that?

Comment: I just flagged your Q for moderator assistance. You could do the same, I suppose, but it wouldn't add any value. The mods could refuse, but that's unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot` does not support multiple y axes (unless they are both numeric and one is a scale of the other). There are numerous posts about this that you can search up for yourself. Here's a work-around that might do the trick for you.

```
example_df <- 
  data.frame(
    statement_a = c("I like to take risks", 
                    "I work to provide for my family"),
    statement_b = c("I am more risk averse",
                    "I work to provide for myself"),
    value = c(-1.5, .5)
  )

row_count <- nrow(example_df)
max_value <- max(abs(example_df$value))

example_df$y <- 1:row_count

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(example_df) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = rep(0, row_count), 
                xmax = value, 
                ymin = y-0.3, ymax = y+0.3)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = -max_value-0.2,
                y = y,
                label = statement_a),
            hjust = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = max_value-0.2,
                y = y,
                label = statement_b),
            hjust = 0) +
  xlim(c(-max_value-10,max_value+10)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: To be clear, there are many posts that talk about `ggplot2` not supporting multiple `scales`, but in this case the `scale` is the same, it's multiple `axes` that I'm looking for.